# MySQL 8.0 timestamp CURRENT_TIMESTAMP sets date to '0000-00-00 00:00:00' (was ok in 5.7)

Tags: mysql-8.0, null, timestamp, default-value

The table T has this field

```
+---------------+--------------+------+-----+-------------------+-----------------------------+
| Field         | Type         | Null | Key | Default           | Extra                       |
+---------------+--------------+------+-----+-------------------+-----------------------------+
| updated       | timestamp    | NO   |     | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP | on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP |
+---------------+--------------+------+-----+-------------------+-----------------------------+
```

In MySQL 5.7, doing an update of a record and setting `updated=null` was automatically setting `updated` to the current date-time

```
UPDATE T SET ...,updated=null WHERE k=123

==> 

+---------------------+
| updated             |
+---------------------+
| 2022-01-05 22:52:05 |
+---------------------+
```

But doing the same in MySQL 8.0, gives

```
+---------------------+
| updated             |
+---------------------+
| 0000-00-00 00:00:00 |
+---------------------+
```

How can I fix that, is this a MySQL bug, or a new setting (or a change in behavior)?

Comment: If you want updated to get the current time, you can use `updated=NOW`, or because it has a `on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`, you can just omit it from the `UPDATE` SQL, and it will get the current timestamp. Its a change in behaviour that was outside specification, is your bug for using it that way :-)

Comment: The thing is I want to change as less code as possible (eg an option in MySQL). It seems that disabling `explicit_defaults_for_timestamp` would get the NULL behavior back, but that option is also deprecated... (and since it's not part of my settings, 5.7 should also *not* have worked like that...)

Comment: Why did you use `updated=null` on the UPDATE in the first place, when the column is defined with `ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` ?

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ There is a need to update the timestamp when no data changed in this table, while some data changed in "child" tables (eg order -> products).

Comment: This behavior depends on the [SQL Server mode](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-mode.html).

Comment: Have a look [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_explicit_defaults_for_timestamp), [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/datetime.html) and [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/timestamp-initialization.html). Now go [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=6da31dfd1e2d2f4e0f221b4721cee519)  and [here](https://sqlize.online/sql/mysql80/fde281987d1e8d9acf6e2c5fe60d1b01/)...

Comment: You can have endless hours of fun trying to figure out the different (ahem...) problems that arise when you switch major and minor versions of MySQL and try to construct the tables in different ways and trying to figure out where the documentation actually aligns with what happens and where it doesn't! Your default for 5.7 on update is to set the first TIMESTAMP field to  CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - even when you haven't asked for this!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably late, but you were on the right track with `explicit_defaults_for_timestamp`.  The key fact is that this variable [defaults to `ON` in version 8.0](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_explicit_defaults_for_timestamp), but it [defaulted to OFF in v.5.7](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_explicit_defaults_for_timestamp).

Comment: I had to figure it by myself eventually. Nice catch anyway, thanks!